# Espaço entre botão e título da Navbar

Tags: html

[Minha Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9bQj.png)

Código HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Vanguard Autos</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
  data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
  aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <div class="btn-nav">
      <button class="btn">
        <img src="images/i1.svg" class="img-btn-nav" alt="location">
        Concessionárias
      </button>
      <button class="btn">
        <img src="images/i0.svg" class="img-btn-nav" alt="user">
        Entrar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Código CSS

```
.bg-dark{
    background-color: var(--backgound-color) !important;
}

.navbar-brand{
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent
}

.btn{
    background-color: var(--backgound-color) !important;
    color:var(--primary-color);
}

.btn-nav{
    padding-right: 5%;
}

.img-btn-nav{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

Quero dar um espaço entre os botões ("Concessionária" e "Entrar") e o título da navbar ("Vanguard Autos"). Já testei 'paddings' e 'margins' mas não deu certo

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Troca o padding, estas propriedades:

```
.btn-nav {
/* padding-right: 5%; */
display: flex;
gap: 2rem; 
}
```